# Is there a way in beautiful soup to count the number of tags in a html page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm looking at creating a dictionary in python where the key is the html tag name and the value is the number of times the tag appeared. Is there a way to do this with beautiful soup or something else?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With BeautifulSoup you can search for all tags by omitting the search criteria:

```
# print all tags
for tag in soup.findAll():
    print tag.name # TODO: add/update dict
```

If you're only interested in the number of occurrences, BeautifulSoup may be a bit overkill in which case you could use the [`HTMLParser`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html) instead:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class print_tags(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print tag # TODO: add/update dict

parser = print_tags()
parser.feed(html)
```

This will produce the same output.

To create the dictionary of `{ 'tag' : count }` you could use [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

occurrences = defaultdict(int)
# ...
occurrences[tag_name] += 1
```

Answer (score 37):

BeautifulSoup is really good for HTML parsing, and you could certainly use it for this purpose.  It would be extremely simple:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

def num_apperances_of_tag(tag_name, html):
    soup = BS(html)
    return len(soup.find_all(tag_name))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my pretty simple solution:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
import requests


class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.start_tags = []
        self.end_tags = []

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        self.start_tags.append(tag)

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        self.end_tags.append(tag)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = MyHTMLParser()

    html_response = requests.get('https://jetlend.ru/')
    parser.feed(html_response.text)

    print('Start tags:', len(parser.start_tags))
    print('End tags:', len(parser.start_tags))
    print('Amount:', len(parser.start_tags) + len(parser.start_tags))
```

source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html