# BeautifulSoup counting tags without parsing deep inside them

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup

I thought about the following [while writing an answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673349/python-xml-parsing-algorithm-speed/27673558#27673558).

Suppose I have a deeply nested `xml` file like this (but much more nested and much longer):

```
<section name="1">
    <subsection name"foo">
        <subsubsection name="bar">
            <deeper name="hey">
                <much_deeper name"yo">
                    <li>Some content</li>
                </much_deeper>
            </deeper>
        </subsubsection>
    </subsection>
</section>
<section name="2">
    ... and so forth
</section>
```

The problem with `len(soup.find_all("section"))` is that while doing `find_all("section")`, BS keeps searching deep into a tag that I know won't contain any other `section` tag.

**So, two questions:**

1. Is there a way to make BS **not** search recursively into an already found tag?
2. If the answer to 1 is yes, will it be more efficient or is it the same internal process?

Comment: `len(soup.find_all('section'))` displays 2 for me. What's your problem in that?

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes indeed, but `soup.find_all('section')` carts around a huge overhead before being passed to `len()`. Or, there's no overhead at all and it's simply a game of passing references. Hence my question :)

Comment: i think there is no other method than this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13853025/is-there-a-way-in-beautiful-soup-to-count-the-number-of-tags-in-a-html-page

Comment: may be you could use regx. `len(re.findall(r'<section\b[^<>]*>', html))`

Comment: not convinced by a regex. Thanks for the suggestion, though. I suppose if `find_all` is the official way of counting, it must be optimised for this purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BeautifulSoup` cannot give you just a count/number of tags it found.

What you, though, can improve is: don't let `BeautifulSoup` go searching sections inside other sections by passing `recursive=False`:

```
len(soup.find_all("section", recursive=False))
```

Aside from that improvement, `lxml` would do the job faster:

```
tree.xpath('count(//section)')
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj sorry, what do you mean by that? Please elaborate. Thanks.

Comment: `soup.find_all("section", recursive=False)` returns an empty list. `len(soup.find_all("section", recursive=False))` displays 0.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. And yes, in this case directly calling `lxml` would be faster I suppose. Do you have any idea if this particular way of using `lxml` makes a full recursive search or it just stays "on the surface"?

Comment: @Jivan I think in this case calling `lxml` directly would be more efficient, because, even that lxml recursively goes through the whole tree to count the occurences of `section`, it does it in C and this is just a counter, it doesn't create `Tag` instances carrying around the children as `find_all()` would do. Hope that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @AvinashRaj should work. I guess it didn't work for you because it is required to turn on `xml` features for `BeautifulSoup` and have a single root element. E.g. this works for me: https://gist.github.com/alecxe/606a1983aabce8068257. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Thank you so much! this was exactly what I was looking for.