# BeautifulSoup dont search recursive in already found tag

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm working at the moment with wikipedia articles containing lists.

I've got now the article [List of Archdeacons in the Diocese in Europe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archdeacons_in_the_Diocese_in_Europe). To get the ul (or table) tags I'm using BeautifulSoup (Python 2.7).
I discovered that the content of the article is contained by the 'mw-content-text' tag:

```
article = soup.find('div', {'id':'mw-content-text'})
lists = article.find_all('ul')
```

So that's how I get the lists and It's working for this example. But there are  articles where a list contains other lists and I don't want BS to track  these sublists. How do I say BS that I don't have to look deeper when It found a tag?

The parameter *recursive* is NOT what I'm looking for because the list might be in a div tag.

P.S.: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673644/beautifulsoup-counting-tags-without-parsing-deep-inside-them/27673808#27673808) user is looking for the same solution but gets not the right answer: "Is there a way to make BS not search recursively into an already found tag?'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach would be to use a [function](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) to search for `ul` tags. For every `ul` tag found check that there is no parent `ul` tags found using [`find_parent()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-parents-and-find-parent):

```
article.find_all(lambda x: x.name == 'ul' and x.find_parent("ul") is None)
```